# How does one import the BSON object successfully in a Zeppelin notebook?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, bson, apache-zeppelin

Does anyone know how to resolve the following BSON object error when calling a MongoDB instance via a Zeppelin notebook?

"error: object bson is not a member of package org import org.bson.BSONObject"

I am specifically implementing the notebook via a Spark cluster in Azure and the code is in Scala. I am using the uber jar "mongo-java-driver-3.2.1.jar". I have also attempted this using the individual three required jars as well as various versions of them and receive the same error.

Here is the code I am executing in the notebook minus the actual IP address for the mongo instance.

```
z.load("C:\\mongojar\\mongo-java-driver-3.2.1.jar")

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.bson.BSONObject
import org.bson.BasicBSONObject

val config = new Configuration()
config.set("mongo.input.uri", "mongodb://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:27017   
/marketdata.minibars")
config.set("mongo.job.input.format",    
"com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat")

val mongoRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(config,     
classOf[com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat], classOf[Object], 
classOf[BSONObject])

mongoRDD.first()
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be that loading the jar failed.
Try this:

```
z.load("org.mongodb:bson:3.2.1").
```

It is also possible that the `SparkContext` requires it too (if it has to be distributed on the cluster), so you should also try:

```
z.loadAndDist("org.mongodb:bson:3.2.1")
```

I just checked, and the latest version of the package does not have the classes `org.bson.BSONObject` and `org.bson.BasicBSONObject` anymore. You could revert back to an older version, like 2.3 by changing the version code, or change your code to conform with the lastest version. [Documentation can be found here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.2/).

Comment: I received a new error with loadAndDist. "value loadAndDist is not a member of org.apache.zeppelin.spark.ZeppelinContext". I also tried z.load("org.mongodb:bson:3.2.1") and no new errors arose. I ran it without the import org.bson.BSONObject and it resulted in the following successful message res340: Iterable[String] = Wrappers(org.mongodb:bson:3.2.1, org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6) .

Comment: That particular line seems to work. The code still yields "error: object BSONObject is not a member of package org.bson" however when it is referenced. A bit puzzling...

Comment: I just edited my question with a promising solution.

Comment: I am looking at that right now Daniel Zolnai and will share if it works. I started briefly digging through the documentation last night to see if something had changed as well but you caught it. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately the error persists after reverting back to the older versions like 2.3 that does include BSONObject as per the documentation at https://api.mongodb.org/java/2.3/. So it appears the answer ultimately ends up being to refactor the code for the newer version although the documentation thus far does not reveal any of its secrets. Working with Spark seems to be 95% trying to configure connectivity and 5% dealing with the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB Support confirmed the jars in question were correct and had the necessary objects. I spoke with Microsoft and as it turns out it does appear to be a Zeppelin issue.

Zeppelin is no longer the recommended solution and they instead recommend the Jupyter notebook for future efforts but it is not ready to support what I am attempting. So instead Microsoft has been able to demo the import of the BSON objects using sbt and a fat jar and then submitted the job with spark-submit.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.bson.BSONObject
import org.bson.BasicBSONObject
import com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat


object MongoTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

  val config = new Configuration()
  config.set("mongo.input.uri", "mongodb://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:27017/marketdata.minibars")
  config.set("mongo.job.input.format", "com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat")

  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MongoTest")
  val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)  

  val mongoRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(config, classOf[com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat], classOf[Object], classOf[BSONObject])    
  mongoRDD.first()


  sc.stop()
}



}
```